# texstudio completion of ntheorem commands

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I want to have Texstudio add completions for some `ntheorem` package commands, including:

```
\begin{Definition}[]
\end{Definition}
```

and

```
\begin{Proposition}[]
\end{Proposition}
```

I looked at the CWL file and could not find references to any of the `\begin{}` and `\end{}` environment definitions, so I was not sure how to add these. Any suggestions on how to include this syntax in the ntheorem.cwl file?

As a reference, I looked at some other posted questions on related topics, but they were just directing users to include the ntheorem.cwl file in the list of completions, but were not asking about syntax.

[Add to TexStudio autocompletion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125815/add-to-texstudio-autocompletion)

[TexStudio autocompletion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237444/texstudio-autocompletion)

[Autocompletion in Texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134581/autocompletion-in-texstudio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is documented in the [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION). Just write the commands as you've done in your examples.

See other cwl files for examples, e.g. [latex-document.cwl](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/latex-document.cwl)

Comment: Okay cool. yeah, I looked over the example in latex-document.cwl and looks much easier than I thought. Thanks for the help.